# how to set focus to next input on enter key press in react js with refs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

Iam using multiple inputs inside maps i want to set focus to next input when i click enter in react Hooks.
With the help of refs

Iam using material ui text field for getting input

I tried in react class component wihtout ref it works with error but in hooks it not works
class compomnent code:

```
constructor(props) {
this.state = {}
}
```

inputRefs = [];

```
 _handleKeyPress = e => {
        const {currentTarget} = e;
            let inputindex = this.inputRefs.indexOf(currentTarget)
            if (inputindex < this.inputRefs.length - 1) {
                this.inputRefs[inputindex + 1].focus()
            }
            else {
                this.inputRefs[0].focus()
            }
      };
```

Inside render in added this within map function

```
this.state.data.map((data) => return (
<TextField 
     inputProps = {{onKeyPress:(e) => this.function1(e, data)}}
     onChange={this.changevaluefunction} 
     inputRef={ref => this.inputRefs.push(ref)} 
     onFocus={this.handleFocus}  ref={`input${id}`} /> ))
```

Comment: You are using the old React ref syntax. Create an array of React refs using `createRef` and access the current value when trying to focus. Can you provide a more comprehensive component code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yes of course you can i updated the question

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented the solution in a different way with the functional component. I have taken the 4 fields and seated its ref with the `createRef` hook.

I can see from your solution, you wanted to move focus to the next input element whenever you press `Enter` key on the current element.

I am passing the next target element argument in the `onKeyUp` handler along with the actual event and then detecting whether the `Enter` key is pressed or not. If `Enter` key is pressed and the `targetElem` is present then I am moving focus to the passed `targetElem`. By this way you have better control over the inputs.

You can see my solution here

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-leftpad-2nx91?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import "./styles.css";

const inputs = [
  {
    id: "fName",
    label: "First Name"
  },
  {
    id: "lName",
    label: "Last Name"
  },
  {
    id: "gender",
    label: "Gender"
  },
  {
    id: "address",
    label: "Address"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const myRefs = useRef([]);

  const handleKeyUp = (e, targetElem) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter" && targetElem) {
      targetElem.focus();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {inputs.map((ipt, i) => (
        <TextField
          onKeyUp={(e) =>
            handleKeyUp(e, myRefs.current[i === inputs.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1])
          }
          inputRef={(el) => (myRefs.current[i] = el)}
          id={ipt.id}
          fullWidth
          style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
          label={ipt.label}
          variant="outlined"
          key={ipt.id}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @swaran nirla thanks for your help you are using dynamic refs how about the input in map function and then how we pass the the array ojbect inside the function

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have updated the code, a/c to your need. Kindly check and upvote this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `this.inputRefs` into a React ref so it persists through renders, and other than this you pretty much remove all references to any `this` object.

Example Component:

```
const LENGTH = 10;
const clamp = (min, max, val) => Math.max(min, Math.min(val, max));

export default function App() {
  const [data] = useState([...Array(LENGTH).keys()]);

  const inputRefs = useRef([]); // <-- ref to hold input refs

  const handleKeyPress = index => () => {                   // <-- enclose in scope
    const nextIndex = clamp(0, data.length - 1, index + 1); // <-- get next index
    inputRefs.current[nextIndex].focus();                   // <-- get ref and focus
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((data, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <TextField
            inputProps={{ onKeyPress: handleKeyPress(index) }}   // <-- pass index
            inputRef={(ref) => (inputRefs.current[index] = ref)} // <-- save input ref
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-set-focus-to-next-input-on-enter-key-press-in-react-js-with-refs]

Comment: thanks for your help sir thank you so much you are awsome, i have one suggession instead of using clamp how if we add one to the index and then focus and also inputRefs.current[nextIndex] && inputRefs.current[nextIndex].focus(); the inputRefs.current[nextIndex].focus() not works. it only works when we give like that. anyway thanks sir.

Answer (score 0):

If you are mapping the input field and want to focus on click, you can directly give the id attribute to the input and pass the array id.

After that, you can pass id inside a function as a parameter, and get it by `document.getElementById(id).focus()`.